The installShield Script we use does not pull Nuget-related DLLS from the solutions Primary output BIN folder, but does its own thing
Using InstallShield 2024R1 with a VB.Net Solution targeting DotNet 4.8 under Visual Studio 2022. We use several Nuget Packages.
The installShield Script we use does not pull Nuget-related DLLS from the Solutions Primary output BIN folder, but from someplace else.
We can see this as not all the DLLs that InstallShield packages up in the install come from that folder. Some of the DLLS from the BIN folder are missing, there are some extra and some have different content but with the same version.
Is there a way just to get InstallShield to use the primary output and only the primary output?
This is a simple case were all i really want (I think) is what is in the BIN folder.
•   Can that be done?
•   Why is InstallShield doing its own thing?
Thanks
